# Is the number of "flag" for moderator attention regenerating up to 10?

Tags: support

Is the number of "flag" you can set for moderator attention regenerating up to 10?

Comment: Who the hell downvotes someone asking a support question like this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Answer (score 2):

Each user who has at least 15 reputation is allowed to use a certain number (anywhere from 10 to 100) of moderator flags per day. The specific number depends on your level of reputation and your previous flagging history. Your personal flag count resets at midnight GMT.